# Floated DIVs overlapping incorrectly

Tags: html, css

In the following code, I'd like the `#nav` div to overlap the `#content` div. Even though `#nav` has a higher z-Index value, it is still being overlapped by `#content`.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Zfcba/

HTML:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="nav"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#page
{
    margin: 20px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

#nav
{
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: inherit;
    border: 1px solid red;
    z-index: 999;
}

#content
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: -20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: inherit;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background: lightgray;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Pretty simple code, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I tried the same without the outer div (http://jsfiddle.net/Zfcba/1). Still the same problem. :(

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/XcYxG/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` only works for `absolute` positioned elements. As the browser ignores the value for `z-index`, it will then render it in the order the elements are in your html-code. As `#content` is later in your code than `#nav`, `#content` will be displayed over `#nav`.

Comment: z-index works for relative and fixed too, only static doesn't emulate z-index property ;).

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your css

```
#above{position:absolute;}
```